# How to make md-action buttons to stick to the bottom of md-card?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How to make buttons inside `md-action` to always stick to bottom of outer `md-card` i.e have static position?

http://codepen.io/ResilientJoe/pen/aNEzBp

Setting `layout-align="end end"` as described here is not working https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment

**UPDATE:**

Addign buttons inside `<md-card-footer>` solved problem since setting static height style property is not appropriate for my case

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that height of md-card-content is dynamic, so if you fix the height of md-card-content, your problem will be resolved.

i.e. add

```
style="height: 150px;"
```

to your md-card-content.

see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwdbWv